# Resign IPA from development to enterprise

Tags: xcode, code-signing, ipa

**Is it possible to resign an .ipa file signed with a development certificate to an enterprise certificate?**

Background: My client needs the .ipa file. He owns the enterprise certificates which he won't share with us. The idea is that I deliver the .ipa file with my own development certificate and deliver it to him. He resigns it using his enterprise certificate so he can deploy his app on his internal app store.

Currently I have my .ipa file signed and I'm ready to submit the file, but I have to be certain it's possible.

I read [this](https://coderwall.com/p/cea3fw/resign-ipa-with-new-distribution-certificate) article but the assumption there is that the provisioning profile is either for Adhoc, or Enterprise distribution .. which is not my case and I don't know if it matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to resign the ipa after it is built.

1. Terminal way - You can try this. https://coderwall.com/p/cea3fw/resign-ipa-with-new-distribution-certificate
2. Tool - https://github.com/xndrs/XReSign - A wonderful tool to resign the IPA.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/) and [resign](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/resign/) command

Installation in Doc.

usage:

1) `fastlane init`

2) `fastlane/Fastlane(file)`

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Resigning Current Provision"
  lane :resigner do
    resign(
      ipa: "location/appName.ipa",    
      signing_identity: "iPhone Distribution: Bbalbalbalbal.xxxxx",
      provisioning_profile: "location/xxxxx.mobileprovision",
    )
    # add actions here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions
  end
end
```

3) run `fastlane ios resigner`

Answer (score 2):

To resign ipa for enterprise or ad-hoc distribution you can follow below simple steps:

To resign app using terminal you can follow below steps:

1. Unzip ipa

   `unzip MyApp.ipa`
2. Remove existing signature

   `rm -rf Payload/MyApp.app/_CodeSignature/`
3. Copy your `Ad-Hoc` or `enterprise` provisioning profile to payload's `embedded` provisioning profile.

   `cp ~/Desktop/MyAdHoc.mobileprovision Payload/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision`
4. Re-sign `.app` file with related code signing identity for `Ad-hoc` or `Enterprise` certificate available in Keychain.

   `codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Code signing Certificate for Enterprise or Ad-hoc app" Payload/MyApp.app`
5. Zip payload and give name of `ipa` you want.

   `zip -qr MyApp_Resigned.ipa Payload/`

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use development binaries for production.**

You should not resign a development binary to enterprise/production binary. Development binaries normally contain lots of extra stuff which lets debug and run all the those tools which help us make our app better. These make the binary larger, slower, use more power and create security risks.

To answer the question, the simplest thing you can do it provide an unsigned app which your customer signs themselves.

1. Archive the app. In Menus do *Product -> Archive*
2. Open the Organizer. *Window -> Organizer*
3. Select the app, then archive you just created.
4. Right click the archive and pick *Show in Finder*.

From there you can either

- Deliver the whole .xcarchive (which is a ZIP file) if you want them to have the debugging info and bits.

or

- Go into the .xcarchive then into *Products -> Applications* and deliver them the unsigned .ipa file there.

This is less work for you and prevents you from running into any pitfalls like accidentally sending them a binary you built for development.