# Is it possible to distribute old app for ad-hoc use?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

A friend commissioned an app to be developed some years ago but the developers went out of business. It was removed from the AppStore in 2015 but she still has it running on 4 devices (she's a university professor and uses it for her research). She now wants to put the app onto other devices and as an app developer myself I'm trying to help.

Is this possible? If so, how?

We've tried to contact the original developers but they are unable to find the source code. Rewriting is out of the question as she can't get funding for this until she can prove her results - for which she needs the app on more devices.

We have managed to get the original .ipa file off one of the existing devices. When I try to put it onto my iPhone using XCode Devices it does it, but when I try to run it it pops up asking for an appstore user name & password and won't go any further, even if I enter my own valid id. Perhaps it's contacting the appstore, finding that the app isn't on there any more and bombing out?

I've tried resigning the .app with an ad-hoc development one using my own developer id but when I try to install that on my iphone it starts doing it then says "The application could not be verified". I've also tried creating a dummy app with the same name and version number and following these instructions [Resign IPA from development to enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051356/resign-ipa-from-development-to-enterprise) but that doesn't work either. I've researched the error message to no avail. I *am* deleting the previous app each time I try to put a new one on.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Your friend should still be able to download it under her account, but she’ll probably need devices running iOS 10 or earlier. Even apps that are removed from sale are still available for download for users that have purchased them.

Comment: Thanks vacawama, yes that proved to be the case. Sadly, no other solution.